# Workaround for Impala Regex lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: sql, regex, hive, impala

If I use Hive, the below works fine. But if I use Impala, it throws error:

```
select regexp_replace("foobarbarfoo","bar(?=bar)","<NA>");

WARNINGS: Could not compile regexp pattern: bar(?=bar)
Error: invalid perl operator: (?=
```

Basically, Impala doesn't support lookahead and lookbehind

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/impala_incompatible_changes.html#incompatible_changes_200

Is there a workaround for this today? Maybe use UDF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `regexp_replace`, match and capture the part of string you want to keep (but want to use as must-have context) and replace with a backreference. See the [`regexp_replace` Impala reference](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_replace):

> These examples show how you can replace parts of a string matching a pattern with replacement text, which can include backreferences to any `()` groups in the pattern string. The backreference numbers start at 1, and any `\`characters must be escaped as `\\`.

So, here, you may use

```
select regexp_replace("foobarbarfoo","bar(bar)","<NA>\\1");
                                         ^   ^       ^^^
```

Note it will not work to replace consecutive matches, however, it will work in the current scenario and [`foobarbarfoo` will turn into `foo<NA>barfoo`](https://regex101.com/r/PMKjAz/2) (note that Go regex engine is also RE2, hence this option is chosen at regex101.com).

Comment: I got `foo<NA>$1foo` is the return. So that backreference `$1` didn't do anything... at least for Impala.

Comment: @HP. Then try `\1` syntax. Either `"<NA>\1"` or `"<NA>\\1"`

Comment: Ah `\\1` works...Where is this mentioned in Cloudera doc? Is there a "forwardreference" too?

Comment: @HP. Yes, just found [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html).